# C# running websocket connection under tor circuit

Tags: c#, tor, socks

I'm creating an application on C# NET 4.0. It's an anonymous messanger, which have to run under tor SOCKS proxy. I know, that tor's proxy is SOCKS5 and it's 127.0.0.1 port 9150.

The connection is not just http requests, but it's websocket protocol. I'm using Websocket4net for connection.

So it has 4 main events:
OnMessage
OnOpen
OnClose
OnError

The connection setup looks like

```
ServerSocket = new Socket("ws://localhost:3000/");
```

So, how do I use tor with this?

Comment: This would've helped me so much...

Comment: How did you solve it?